# Directory of a network shared folder

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to access the directory of a file which is network shared in the client system, through my JSP application. Is it possible to obtain the directory structure by any means ? I'm trying to develop a project for an event listener on the directory where the file is located (i.e) to log any events that occur in that directory.

Comment: Web browsers don't have access to the client file system, for security reasons.

Comment: @Andreas I knew that much. I read some where that network shared file paths are accessible ! Is that true ? Can you suggest some way around for my situation ! Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: The network shared files are part of "client file system". If you need access to that, then you need to install code for that, e.g. a Java Web Start program.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try ! :)

Comment: @Andreas To be pedantic, it's the use of _http_ that doesn't allow access to the client file system through the browser. Most browsers will let you access the local file system using the _file_ protocol.

Comment: @skomisa I think you're confusing what's running where. Most *browsers* only run JavaScript, and doesn't allow the JavaScript to access the file system from a *remote* web page.